# Highcharts Funnel/Pyramid labels issue

Tags: highcharts, label

I have a display issue when activating legend on a funnel/pyramid Hicharts.
In fact, when I unselect an item in the legend, the slice is correctly hide on the chart but the data labels are moved with a wrong horizontal place.
You can see the result here : https://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/056Lyq8a

Activation of the legend is made by options :
`showInLegend: true`
in the plotOptions.

When you click on an item in the legend (ex. "Requested price list"), you can see the data labels moved inside the chart.

How to make the data labels stay on the left ?

Comment: Hi, the issue has been identified as a bug and has already been fixed. You can find more details here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/17545. The fix will be available in the upcoming release. Alternatively, you can use the master branch to access the solution right away.

Comment: Thanks for this information. Can you give me an approximative date for the upcoming release please ?

Comment: It's hard to say, because we've just recently released, but usually, it takes ~two months. You can track the changelog here: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/changelog/ . Here is the working demo based on the master branch as the temporarly solution: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jnfve6rg/